# reading the last index from a csv file using pandas in python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pandas, pandasql

I have a .csv file on disk, formatted so that I can read it into a pandas DataFrame easily, to which I periodically write rows. I need this database to have a row index, so every time I write a new row to it I need to know the index of the last row written.

There are plenty of ways to do this:

- I could read the entire file into a DataFrame, append my row, and then print the entire DataFrame to memory again. This might get a bit slow as the database grows.
- I could read the entire index column into memory, and pick the largest value off, then append my row to the .csv file. This might be a little better, depending on how column-reading is implemented.

I am curious if there is a way to just get that one cell directly, without having to read a whole bunch of extra information into memory. Any suggestions?

Comment: you could just write a 1 line file out that has just the last index value when ever you commit to db and then read this file each time and update, also can't you just query the db for this info?

Comment: Yes, I could query the DB, but that would require reading it into memory. Saving the last index in another file is probably the best bet.

Comment: I mean simply asking for the highest/last index value only not specifically reading the entire table into memory

Comment: I don't see how, though. It's technically just a csv file, not a SQL db, so the only way to query it that I am aware of is to read it into memory and then query it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the entire index column will still need to read and parse the whole file.

If no fields in the file are multiline, you could scan the file backwards to find the first newline (but with a check if there is a newline past the data). The value following that newline will be your last index.

Storing the last index in another file would also be a possibility, but you would have to make sure both files stay consistent.

Another way would be to reserve some (fixed amount of) bytes at the beginning of the file and write (in place) the last index value there as a comment. But your parser would have to *support* comments, or be able to skip rows.

Comment: Storing the index in another file is possible, but could run into consistency issues. I will have to think about that. Scanning the file backwards is something I hadn't thought about, but I don't think I can guarantee that there are no multiline fields.

Comment: @KBriggs - In that case I would store the index value at the beginning of the file, padded with spaces to make sure the total length is always the same (for in place editing/writing) - for example: `# last index: _______123\n` (where the _ are spaces).

Comment: Is it possible to edit only the first line of a file without having to rewrite the rest of it?

Comment: @KBriggs - Yes, as long as the data is the same width (otherwise all the following data would have to be shifted, which is not wat we want). You might need to open the file in binary mode though (don't know about Python, so I can't provide an example), but it would be like: open file, _seek_ to begin, write 20 bytes (which will automatically overwrite the existing bytes).

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it.